# ConstructingParser: Could not load valid XML document from File

Tags: xml, scala

my XML looks like

```
 $cat /tmp/person.xml
 <root xmlns="http://www.nyorg.com/metadata/config" xmlns:core="http://www.myorg.com/metadata/commonschematypes" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xschema/AppConfig.xsd">
    <!-- This is important comment about person-->
    <person>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Doe</lastName>
      <email>john.doe@noone.com</email>
      <city>SomeWhere</city>
      <property name="myName" value="someValue" />
    </person>
  </root>
```

I try to load it as

```
val source = io.Source.fromURL(new java.io.File("/tmp/person.xml").toURL)
val d = scala.xml.parsing.ConstructingParser.fromSource(source, preserveWS = true)
val doc = d.document()
```

What I see is

```
:1:1: < expected<root xmlns="http://www.nyorg.com/metadata/config" xmlns:core="http://www.myorg.com/metadata/commonschematypes" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xschema/AppConfig.xsd">^
doc: scala.xml.Document = null
```

On the other hand when I try to load it with `XML.loadFile`, it works

```
val doc = XML.loadFile("/tmp/person.xml")
println(doc)
```

I see

```
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xschema/AppConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:core="http://www.myorg.com/metadata/commonschematypes" xmlns="http://www.nyorg.com/metadata/config">

    <person>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Doe</lastName>
      <email>john.doe@noone.com</email>
      <city>SomeWhere</city>
      <property value="someValue" name="myName"/>
    </person>
  </root>
```

What am I doing wrong with `ConstructingParser`?

Answer (score 0):

The line which made all the differences is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

As soon as I changed my file to include this line

```
cat /tmp/person.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.nyorg.com/metadata/config" xmlns:core="http://www.myorg.com/metadata/commonschematypes" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xschema/AppConfig.xsd">
    <!-- This is important comment about person-->
    <person>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Doe</lastName>
      <email>john.doe@noone.com</email>
      <city>SomeWhere</city>
      <property name="myName" value="someValue" />
    </person>
  </root>
```

My code started to work

```
root: scala.xml.Node = <root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../xschema/AppConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:core="http://www.myorg.com/metadata/commonschematypes" xmlns="http://www.nyorg.com/metadata/config">
    <!-- This is important comment about person-->
    <person>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Doe</lastName>
      <email>john.doe@noone.com</email>
      <city>SomeWhere</city>
      <property value="someValue" name="myName"/>
    </person>
  </root>
```

The problem remains is that even `ConstructingParser` reorders the attributes, but that is for another StackOverflow question